# Autodesk Revit in particular doesn't work in WMR desktop

Tags: virtual-reality, revit, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to use Revit in VR while inside a realtime rendering of the model. WMR desktop doesn't let me click on the toolbars but SteamVR desktop does.
See this link to a video of the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5inunjyj9jx8w0i/WMR%20Issue.mp4?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: We don't know what technology Autodesk uses to implement this Ribbon Menu, so it's difficult to help you locate the problem. It is recommended that you feedback this bug to AutoDesk for faster professional help.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT thanks, I am reaching out to Autodesk also. So far you're more responsive : ) But if you saw towards the end of the video I posted, it works fine in the Steam Desktop, but not in the WMR one. Problem is the Steam Desktop is static and terrible. I'll keep trying Autodesk.